# Rails, code organization, where to keep map/reducer scripts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I know this is sort of a strange question, but as a neat freak I wanted to ask some pros about best practices on organizing my code.

So we pretty much have ~10 map/reduce tasks (which are used by MongoDB) that all usually run in the background (with redis-scheduler), but there is quite a bit of code there and I don't want it to load unless explicitly stated, if I put it in my `lib` directory, won't it load in the app on production even when just booted by my web server? The fact that no user action in the app will make use of that particular code.

So my question is, where should I keep them all, and how should I organize them?

Comment: Since they're never executed from the application itself, could you place them under `script` and execute them with `rails runner`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of Rails's autoloading is that the code won't be loaded into memory until you first reference it. For example, I created a class called `Thing`:

```
# app/concerns/thing.rb
class Thing
  puts "Loaded Thing"
end
```

Loading the Rails console doesn't print anything until I create an instance of `Thing`:

```
[ruby-1.9.2-p290@so_test_app test_app: 505]$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.1)
1.9.2p290 :001 > Thing.new
Loaded Thing
#<Thing:0x000001039c81b0>
1.9.2p290 :002 >
```

So I'd say you're safe organizing your code under `lib` (assuming you've added that to your `autoload_paths`) without negatively impacting your code footprint in memory.

---

**Edit:** Well, I changed my mind. The classes do get loaded at boot time in the production environment:

```
[ruby-1.9.2-p290@so_test_app test_app: 508]$ rails c production
Loaded Thing
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.1)
1.9.2p290 :001 >
```

I'll have to put some more thought into this.

Comment: Hey Brandan thanks for your help, I really appreciate it! Yah, huh? it just seems messy to like put it in like another directory that isn't in my load path, I guess it's a pretty good assumption on the rails team part, why would you want your code to *not* load? lol.